# How do i count json objects in a django rest framework external API and return the total?

Tags: django-rest-framework, fetch-api

how do i count the json objects returned by the api and visualise the count in some sort of a html table.The api is an external Django rest framework api.
[image: The json objects returned are as shown]

I am quite puzzled since this particular api is external thus there's no particular model whose json objects we are trying to count.

any idea on how this can be done will really be appreciated.

Comment: Specify what exactly do you want? 
Do you want to get the number of instances and do something with them? It possible to get by ORM. Or do you want the endpoint to display the number of entries on the page? It possible to get using pagination class.

Comment: i want to count those objects from the endpoint and return a value of the total objects in the data dictionary in a html file. The endpoint is a Public Django rest API. imagine there was an API URL endpoint of a Django rest API whose objects are in JSON and you would like to count those objects and return value.